# 404 error GET bad request Rapid API React.js, get sneakerId from the api url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, http-status-code-404

In my application I am using an api that gets sneaker information. when trying to get the sneaker by id with the 'getSneakerById' endpoint. I want to change the url so I'm able to pass the sneakerId so that I can reach the sneakerId component and get the sneaker data. in my component I'm using a useEffect to bring in the 'getById' function from my 'api' file that brings in the data so I can add the id to the end of the url endpoint.

[image: error in terminal]

api file

```
import axios from "axios";

const API_KEY = process.env.RAPID_API_KEY
export default {

getData: () =>
axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://v1-sneakers.p.rapidapi.com/v1/sneakers',
  params: {limit: '100'},
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'f2326766a3msh573dd850eaeab1fp181777jsnf7f3daf5cc0a',
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'v1-sneakers.p.rapidapi.com'
  }

}),

getDataId: (id) => 
  axios({
    method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://v1-sneakers.p.rapidapi.com/v1/sneakers/' + id,
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'f2326766a3msh573dd850eaeab1fp181777jsnf7f3daf5cc0a',
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'v1-sneakers.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
  })


}
```

sneakerId component

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import api from '../api';



const SneakerId = ({id}) => {
    const [sneaker, setSneaker] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData =  () => {
        api.getDataId(id).then((response) => {
            setSneaker(response.results);
            console.log(response.results);
            
          });
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [id]);
    
  

    return (
        <div className="single_sneaker_container">
            {sneaker && (
                <div className="sneaker_Description">
                    <h2>{sneaker.name}</h2>
                </div>
            )}
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default SneakerId
```

App.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './components/Home'; 
import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import SneakerId from './components/SneakerId';


 const App = () => {

   
       

     
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Navbar />
                   
                    <Home />
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/:id">
                <SneakerId id={id}/>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default App;
```

home.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import api from '../api';
import '../stylesheets/shoeList.css';
import placeholder from '../images/cooming.jpeg'
// import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';
// import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar';
import SingleSneaker from './SingleSneaker';


const Home = () => {
// const [data, SetData] = useState([]);
  const [sneakers, setSneakerData] = useState([]);

  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);
  const [result, setResult] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      api.getData().then((response) => {
        setSneakerData(response.data.results);
        setFiltered(response.data.results);
        console.log(response.data.results);
        
      });
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
      const results = filtered.filter(sneaker=> sneaker.shoe.toLowerCase().includes(result));
      setSneakerData(results);
      
    
  },[result]);

  const onChange =(e)=> {
    setResult(e.target.value);
}

  return (
    <div className="sneakerList-container">
          <div className="searchBar__container">
            <div className="searchBar_field">
                <div className="searchText_phrase">
                <h3>Search shoes <span className="color">below</span></h3>
                </div>
                <div className="search_input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." value={result} onChange={onChange}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
      
      {sneakers && (
        <div className="sneakerlist">
          {sneakers.map((sneaker) => {
            return (
                <SingleSneaker key={sneaker.id} id={sneaker.id} name={sneaker.name} shoe={sneaker.shoe} img={sneaker.media.imageUrl}/>
          
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: You are not actually inserting the sneakerId into the URL anywhere (and not even remotely trying to do so...?). Also please do not post code as image. Anyway, you need to use `url: "https://.../sneakers/" + sneakerId` and pass that `sneakerId` as param to your `getDataId` function. In your sneaker component, you need to then use `api.getDataId(123)` or whatever so that actually ends up as part of the URL. This is essentially parameter passing and string composition, it's not really about APIs or React but very basic mechanisms.

Comment: I understand that I need to pass sneakerId to the end of the url, I tried that earlier but was confused on how to go about it. I'm not familiar with using an api from a file like this. I'm also confused on how I can get the url in the component and pass the sneakerId. I will also edit the original post.

Comment: Don't make this more complicated than it is. You need to a) pass a parameter and b) add it to the end of a string. It's hard to get more basic than that. You still have `api.getDataId()` in that code, which means you are not passing anything to the function. Also, `[object Object]` is when you force an object into a string. Your what exactly is the format of `sneakerId`? Is it a number? Text?

Comment: Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-nightingale-098lx?file=/src/SneakerId.js (note that with axios, the server's reply is in the `.data` field, not `.results`)

Comment: `my problem is getting the id into the api file` you are calling a function. Yes, it is declared in another file, but how does that matter? Just declare parameters then pass arguments, like with any other function.

Comment: To be clear, solving your issue is just marginally more complex than this: https://jsfiddle.net/L6my43ch/

Comment: I'm sorry I should've been more clear I edited the original post. I've added the home.js and the app.js. when trying what you did in the code sandbox the id comes back as undefined in the url and a 404 error.

Comment: Ok, we're slowly getting somewhere. Currently, the `id` in `<SneakerId id={id}/>` is still undefined because you're not following the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params) of react router. `const SneakerId = ({id})` won't work here; you need `let { id } = useParams();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you're not passing your ID anywhere. Pass an ID as a parameter to your component

```
const SneakerId = ({id}) => { ... }

export default SneakerId
```

Also pass it as an argument to your API request

```
getDataId: (id) => {
  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `https://your_host/v1/sneakers/${id}`,
    headers: {...}
  })
}
```

Comment: my problem is getting the id into the api file.

Comment: I've posted a full `getDataId` method with ID argument above

Comment: I did that and now this error shows '[object%20Object]'. at the end of the url in the terminal its a 400 bad  request now.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to wrap id in curly braces in SneakerId component =)

Comment: thanks but not it shows this error it this because of the AP? 'vendors~main.chunk.js:554 GET https://v1-sneakers.p.rapidapi.com/v1/sneakersundefined 403 (Forbidden)'

Comment: @Wadaygo Just look at the error. It is very obvious what's happening. 1. you forgot the final slash 2. `id` is `undefined` because you're still not passing it

Comment: Have you read this one before start? https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html